# Alfa Networks Realtek RTL8187 Wireless USB Network Adapter; I need an extension for the "co-axial" connector to the antenna

Tags: wiring, coaxial

Basically, I need to be able to mount my actual network antenna somewhat farther away from my computer than Alfa's included hardware will allow. I need an extension cable to go from my antenna hardware to my network adapter hardware. What kind of cable am I looking for?

Comment: maybe an SMA/RG58?

Comment: Probably RP-SMA connector... You can get them all over the internet, for example Amazon https://www.amazon.com/Antenna-RP-SMA-Extension-Cable-Router/dp/B005C8AYG0 (as an example, not a recommendation) but don't skimp on the cable, cheap cables or bad connectors can induce significant loss to the point that you would be better off just to leave the antenna behind your desk on the floor.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cables you can "extend".

USB:
USB cables are the easiest thing to "extend", as long as you don't really want to go past about 5-meters.  They're all pretty standard.  Just make sure that you get a cable that has the same ends as the one you have now.  (USB-A end?  maybe micro usb? ... not sure)

RF:
Alfa devices can have a few types of connectors.  (yes... they don't actually have a single connector that works on all of their devices).  It's possible that it is a simple SMA connector, or RP-SMA.  I've even seen N and F-Type connectors on alfa devices.  To give a more specific answer, we need the exact model of the alfa device... instead of the wifi chipset.

Comment: apparently.  Alfa adapters connect via USB to the PC.

Comment: LOL...I totally missed it. It's right there in the title.